# Visual Studio 2019 is pushing only git files to remote repository

Tags: git, bitbucket, visual-studio-2019

When I create a .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2019 and add it to source control the local repo is created without any errors. But when I try to use Team Explorer to publish the local repo to a private BiBucket repository, only the .gitattributes and .gitignore files are pushed to the remote master. I cannot see any of my project files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `git add` on the files in your project.  I'm not sure how that's done in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is you need to check the status of git using `git status`.
After that, you can use `git add .` to add the file you want to commit.

Example of my case:

```
 git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   package-lock.json
        modified:   package.json
        modified:   public/index.html
        modified:   src/App.js
```

Answer (score 0):

right-click on the file in Visual studio and from git option chose Add Ignored file to source control and when you did just push your changes